# How can I add a bubble chat icon on my website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, web-frontend

I'm having trouble customizing this code to have a bubble chat icon that stays within my website when I scroll down. Anyone with an idea of how I can improve it?
Here is my code so far:

```html
<!-- Add this script tag without any modification to the target webpage -->
<script type="application/javascript">
  var ciscoBubbleChat = (function() {
    var smHost = 'socialminer.uonbi.ac.ke';
    var widgetId = '1';

    var msgMustAcceptCert = 'Certificate must be accepted to start the conversation.';
    var msgAcceptCertButtonLabel = 'Accept Certificate';
    var msgCloseButtonLabel = 'Close';
    var msgWaitingCertAcceptance = 'Waiting for certificate acceptance.';
    var msgConnectivityIssues = 'We are experiencing connectivity issues. Try later.';

    var appId = 'cisco_bubble_chat';
    var appMargin = 15;
    var appUrl = 'https://' + smHost + '/ccp/ui/BubbleChat.html?host=' + smHost + '&wid=' + widgetId;
    var connectivityCheckUrl = 'https://' + smHost + '/ccp/ui/ConnectivityCheck.html';
    var messageEventListener;
    var addNoCacheQueryParam;
    return {
      showChatWindow: function(injectedData) {
        var logPrefix = 'CISCO_BUBBLE_CHAT: ';
        if (document.getElementById(appId)) {
          console.log(logPrefix + 'Not loading BubbleChat as it is already loaded');
          return;
        }

        var validateInjectedData = function(formData) {
          // browser compatible way to check whether it is an object with 10 fields and all the values are strings
          var result = true;
          if (formData && typeof formData === 'object' && formData.constructor === Object) {
            var counter = 0;
            for (var key in formData) {
              if (!(typeof formData[key] === 'string' || formData[key] instanceof String)) {
                result = false;
                break;
              }
              counter++;
              if (counter > 10) {
                result = false;
                break;
              }
            }
          } else {
            result = false;
          }
          return result;
        };

        if (injectedData) {
          if (validateInjectedData(injectedData.formData)) {
            appUrl += '&injectedFormData=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(injectedData.formData));
          } else {
            if (typeof injectedData.validationErrorCallback === 'function') {
              injectedData.validationErrorCallback();
            } else {
              console.log(logPrefix + 'Could not invoke validationErrorCallback as it is not a function');
            }
          }
        }

        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.setAttribute('sandbox', 'allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-popups');
        iframe.setAttribute('id', appId);
        iframe.setAttribute('style', 'position: fixed; width: 312px; height: 410px; border: none; bottom: 0px; right: 0; z-index:999;');
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        var frameWindow = iframe.contentWindow ? iframe.contentWindow : iframe;
        var frameDoc = frameWindow.document;

        // Trigger a page load for iframe inline content loading to work in Firefox
        frameDoc.open();
        frameDoc.close();

        frameDoc.body.innerHTML = '<div id="secure-connectivity-check-container" style="position: fixed; width: 300px; height: 395px; ' +
          'bottom: 10px; right: 10px; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; color: #4F5051;' +
          'box-shadow: 0 0 3px #000; background: #fff; display: flex; flex-direction: column; display: none;">' +
          '<div style="height: 25%;"></div>' +
          '<div style="height: 25%; display: flex; align-items: flex-start; justify-content: center; text-align: center;">' +
          '<div style="padding: 0 15% 0 15%;">' +
          '<div id="secure-connectivity-check-msg"></div>' +
          '<a id="accept-cert-button" style="display:none; padding-top: 10px" href="#" onclick="acceptCertificate(); return void(0);">' +
          msgAcceptCertButtonLabel +
          '</a>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div style="height: 25%; display: flex; align-items: flex-end; justify-content: center; text-align: center;">' +
          '<div style="padding: 0 15% 0 15%;">' +
          '<a href="#" onclick="window.parent.postMessage({messageType: \'unmount\'}, \'*\'); return void(0);">' +
          msgCloseButtonLabel +
          '</a>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div style="height: 25%;"></div>' +
          '</div>';

        frameWindow.acceptCertificate = function() {
          frameDoc.getElementById('secure-connectivity-check-msg').innerHTML = msgWaitingCertAcceptance;
          frameDoc.getElementById('accept-cert-button').style.display = 'none';
          window.open(addNoCacheQueryParam(connectivityCheckUrl), 'SM_CERT_PAGE');
        };

        if (!addNoCacheQueryParam) {
          addNoCacheQueryParam = function(url) {
            return url + (url.indexOf("?") === -1 ? '?' : '&') + 'nocache=' + new Date().getTime();
          }
        }

        if (!messageEventListener) {
          messageEventListener = function(event) {
            console.log(logPrefix + 'Received event from origin: ' + event.origin);
            console.log(logPrefix + 'Received event data: ' + JSON.stringify(event.data));
            switch (event.data.messageType) {
              case 'resize':
                document.getElementById(appId).style.height = event.data.height + appMargin + 'px';
                console.log(logPrefix + 'Successfully resized');
                break;
              case 'unmount':
                document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById(appId));
                window.removeEventListener('message', messageEventListener);
                console.log(logPrefix + 'Successfully unmounted BubbleChat and removed event listener for message');
                break;
              case 'bubblechat-cert-accepted':
                document.getElementById(appId).setAttribute('src', addNoCacheQueryParam(appUrl));
                console.log(logPrefix + 'Successfully validated certificate acceptance and loaded BubbleChat');
                break;
              default:
                console.log(logPrefix + 'Unknown message type');
            }
          };
        }

        window.addEventListener('message', messageEventListener);
        console.log(logPrefix + 'Event listener for message added');

        // Check HTTPS connectivity and show appropriate screen
        var showConnectivityIssue = function(message, showAcceptCertLink) {
          window.postMessage({
            messageType: 'resize',
            height: 395
          }, '*');
          frameDoc.getElementById('secure-connectivity-check-container').style.display = 'block';
          frameDoc.getElementById('secure-connectivity-check-msg').innerHTML = message;
          frameDoc.getElementById('accept-cert-button').style.display = showAcceptCertLink ? 'block' : 'none';
        };
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState === 4) {
            console.log(logPrefix + 'Connectivity check status: ' + this.status);
            switch (this.status) {
              case 200:
                iframe.setAttribute('src', addNoCacheQueryParam(appUrl));
                break;
              case 0:
                showConnectivityIssue(msgMustAcceptCert, true);
                break;
              default:
                showConnectivityIssue(msgConnectivityIssues, false);
            }
          }
        };
        console.log(logPrefix + 'Checking connectivity to: ' + connectivityCheckUrl);
        xhr.open('GET', addNoCacheQueryParam(connectivityCheckUrl), true);
        xhr.send();
      }
    };
  })();
</script>
<!--
    Use the function 'ciscoBubbleChat.showChatWindow() as the event handler for initiating chat.
    eg: <button onclick="ciscoBubbleChat.showChatWindow()">Start Chat</button>

    Optionally, invisible form data can be submitted, which will be submitted along with the fields customer fills in.
    Upto 10 fields can be passed. If more than 10 fields are passed, the invisible form data will not be used and
    the provided error callback will be invoked. For injecting form data, an object should be passed to
    ciscoBubbleChat.showChatWindow() as an argument. The object should be of the form:
    {
        formData: {
            InjectedField1: 'InjectedValue1',
            InjectedField2: 'InjectedValue2'
            ...
        },
        validationErrorCallback: function(){console.log('business specific logic goes here');}
    }
    The form data can have any string as field name and value. The submitted invisible form data values will be
    shown in the agent desktop, as well as will be updated in ContextService if the specified fieldset(s) in the widget
    contains these field names just like the regular visible chat form fields data.
    eg:
        <button onclick="ciscoBubbleChat.showChatWindow({
            formData: {
                AnyFieldName1: 'AnyFieldValue1',
                AnyFieldName2: 'AnyFieldValue2',
                AnyFieldName3: 'AnyFieldValue3',
                AnyFieldName4: 'AnyFieldValue4',
                AnyFieldName5: 'AnyFieldValue5',
                AnyFieldName6: 'AnyFieldValue6',
                AnyFieldName7: 'AnyFieldValue7',
                AnyFieldName8: 'AnyFieldValue8',
                AnyFieldName9: 'AnyFieldValue9',
                AnyFieldName10: 'AnyFieldValue10'
            },
            validationErrorCallback: function(){console.log('error in validating injected data');}
        })">Click to chat</button>
-->
<html>

<body>
  <button class onclick="ciscoBubbleChat.showChatWindow()">Start Chat</button>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to customize it so that it can have a better look, and find a way to keep it within my website. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to add `position: fixed;` on the button, for example: 
 `<button style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0;" onclick="ciscoBubbleChat.showChatWindow()">Start Chat</button>` 
That would force the button to stay on the lower right side of screen at all times. And for the icon, just add an `<img>` tag.

### **Demo:**

```css
.chatBtn {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 20px;
 right: 20px;
 z-index: 2;
}

.chatBtn img {
 width: 40px; /* Change this to what you want. */
 height: 40px; /* Change this to what you want. */
}
```

```html
<button class="chatBtn" onclick="ciscoBubbleChat.showChatWindow()"><img src="https://icon-library.com/images/talk-bubble-icon-png/talk-bubble-icon-png-2.jpg"> <!-- You can put your own image here. -->
</button>



<!-- Add this script tag without any modification to the target webpage -->
<script type="application/javascript">
    var ciscoBubbleChat = (function () {
        var smHost = 'socialminer.uonbi.ac.ke';
        var widgetId = '1';

        var msgMustAcceptCert = 'Certificate must be accepted to start the conversation.';
        var msgAcceptCertButtonLabel = 'Accept Certificate';
        var msgCloseButtonLabel = 'Close';
        var msgWaitingCertAcceptance = 'Waiting for certificate acceptance.';
        var msgConnectivityIssues = 'We are experiencing connectivity issues. Try later.';

        var appId = 'cisco_bubble_chat';
        var appMargin = 15;
        var appUrl = 'https://' + smHost + '/ccp/ui/BubbleChat.html?host=' + smHost + '&wid=' + widgetId;
        var connectivityCheckUrl = 'https://' + smHost + '/ccp/ui/ConnectivityCheck.html';
        var messageEventListener;
        var addNoCacheQueryParam;
        return {
            showChatWindow: function (injectedData) {
                var logPrefix = 'CISCO_BUBBLE_CHAT: ';
                if (document.getElementById(appId)) {
                    console.log(logPrefix + 'Not loading BubbleChat as it is already loaded');
                    return;
                }

                var validateInjectedData = function(formData) {
                    // browser compatible way to check whether it is an object with 10 fields and all the values are strings
                    var result = true;
                    if (formData && typeof formData === 'object' && formData.constructor === Object){
                        var counter = 0;
                        for (var key in formData) {
                            if (!(typeof formData[key] === 'string' || formData[key] instanceof String)) {
                                result = false;
                                break;
                            }
                            counter++;
                            if (counter > 10) {
                                result = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        result = false;
                    }
                    return result;
                };

                if (injectedData) {
                    if (validateInjectedData(injectedData.formData)) {
                        appUrl += '&injectedFormData=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(injectedData.formData));
                    } else {
                        if (typeof injectedData.validationErrorCallback === 'function') {
                            injectedData.validationErrorCallback();
                        } else {
                            console.log(logPrefix + 'Could not invoke validationErrorCallback as it is not a function');
                        }
                    }
                }

                var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                iframe.setAttribute('sandbox', 'allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-popups');
                iframe.setAttribute('id', appId);
                iframe.setAttribute('style', 'position: fixed; width: 312px; height: 410px; border: none; bottom: 0px; right: 0; z-index:999;');
                document.body.appendChild(iframe);
                var frameWindow = iframe.contentWindow ? iframe.contentWindow : iframe;
                var frameDoc = frameWindow.document;

                // Trigger a page load for iframe inline content loading to work in Firefox
                frameDoc.open();
                frameDoc.close();

                frameDoc.body.innerHTML =   '<div id="secure-connectivity-check-container" style="position: fixed; width: 300px; height: 395px; ' +
                                            'bottom: 10px; right: 10px; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; color: #4F5051;' +
                                            'box-shadow: 0 0 3px #000; background: #fff; display: flex; flex-direction: column; display: none;">' +
                                                '<div style="height: 25%;"></div>' +
                                                '<div style="height: 25%; display: flex; align-items: flex-start; justify-content: center; text-align: center;">' +
                                                    '<div style="padding: 0 15% 0 15%;">' +
                                                        '<div id="secure-connectivity-check-msg"></div>' +
                                                        '<a id="accept-cert-button" style="display:none; padding-top: 10px" href="#" onclick="acceptCertificate(); return void(0);">' +
                                                            msgAcceptCertButtonLabel +
                                                        '</a>' +
                                                    '</div>' +
                                                '</div>' +
                                                '<div style="height: 25%; display: flex; align-items: flex-end; justify-content: center; text-align: center;">' +
                                                    '<div style="padding: 0 15% 0 15%;">' +
                                                        '<a href="#" onclick="window.parent.postMessage({messageType: \'unmount\'}, \'*\'); return void(0);">' +
                                                            msgCloseButtonLabel +
                                                        '</a>' +
                                                    '</div>' +
                                                '</div>' +
                                                '<div style="height: 25%;"></div>' +
                                            '</div>';

                frameWindow.acceptCertificate = function () {
                    frameDoc.getElementById('secure-connectivity-check-msg').innerHTML = msgWaitingCertAcceptance;
                    frameDoc.getElementById('accept-cert-button').style.display = 'none';
                    window.open(addNoCacheQueryParam(connectivityCheckUrl), 'SM_CERT_PAGE');
                };

                if (!addNoCacheQueryParam){
                    addNoCacheQueryParam = function (url) {
                        return url + (url.indexOf("?") === -1 ? '?' : '&') + 'nocache=' + new Date().getTime();
                    }
                }

                if (!messageEventListener) {
                    messageEventListener = function (event) {
                        console.log(logPrefix + 'Received event from origin: ' + event.origin);
                        console.log(logPrefix + 'Received event data: ' + JSON.stringify(event.data));
                        switch (event.data.messageType) {
                        case 'resize':
                            document.getElementById(appId).style.height = event.data.height + appMargin + 'px';
                            console.log(logPrefix + 'Successfully resized');
                            break;
                        case 'unmount':
                            document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById(appId));
                            window.removeEventListener('message', messageEventListener);
                            console.log(logPrefix + 'Successfully unmounted BubbleChat and removed event listener for message');
                            break;
                        case 'bubblechat-cert-accepted':
                            document.getElementById(appId).setAttribute('src', addNoCacheQueryParam(appUrl));
                            console.log(logPrefix + 'Successfully validated certificate acceptance and loaded BubbleChat');
                            break;
                        default:
                            console.log(logPrefix + 'Unknown message type');
                        }
                    };
                }

                window.addEventListener('message', messageEventListener);
                console.log(logPrefix + 'Event listener for message added');

                // Check HTTPS connectivity and show appropriate screen
                var showConnectivityIssue = function (message, showAcceptCertLink) {
                    window.postMessage({ messageType: 'resize', height: 395 }, '*');
                    frameDoc.getElementById('secure-connectivity-check-container').style.display = 'block';
                    frameDoc.getElementById('secure-connectivity-check-msg').innerHTML = message;
                    frameDoc.getElementById('accept-cert-button').style.display = showAcceptCertLink ? 'block' : 'none';
                };
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (this.readyState === 4) {
                        console.log(logPrefix + 'Connectivity check status: ' + this.status);
                        switch (this.status) {
                        case 200:
                            iframe.setAttribute('src', addNoCacheQueryParam(appUrl));
                            break;
                        case 0:
                            showConnectivityIssue(msgMustAcceptCert, true);
                            break;
                        default:
                            showConnectivityIssue(msgConnectivityIssues, false);
                        }
                    }
                };
                console.log(logPrefix + 'Checking connectivity to: ' + connectivityCheckUrl);
                xhr.open('GET', addNoCacheQueryParam(connectivityCheckUrl), true);
                xhr.send();
            }
        };
    })();
</script>
<!--
    Use the function 'ciscoBubbleChat.showChatWindow() as the event handler for initiating chat.
    eg: <button onclick="ciscoBubbleChat.showChatWindow()">Start Chat</button>

    Optionally, invisible form data can be submitted, which will be submitted along with the fields customer fills in.
    Upto 10 fields can be passed. If more than 10 fields are passed, the invisible form data will not be used and
    the provided error callback will be invoked. For injecting form data, an object should be passed to
    ciscoBubbleChat.showChatWindow() as an argument. The object should be of the form:
    {
        formData: {
            InjectedField1: 'InjectedValue1',
            InjectedField2: 'InjectedValue2'
            ...
        },
        validationErrorCallback: function(){console.log('business specific logic goes here');}
    }
    The form data can have any string as field name and value. The submitted invisible form data values will be
    shown in the agent desktop, as well as will be updated in ContextService if the specified fieldset(s) in the widget
    contains these field names just like the regular visible chat form fields data.
    eg:
        <button onclick="ciscoBubbleChat.showChatWindow({
            formData: {
                AnyFieldName1: 'AnyFieldValue1',
                AnyFieldName2: 'AnyFieldValue2',
                AnyFieldName3: 'AnyFieldValue3',
                AnyFieldName4: 'AnyFieldValue4',
                AnyFieldName5: 'AnyFieldValue5',
                AnyFieldName6: 'AnyFieldValue6',
                AnyFieldName7: 'AnyFieldValue7',
                AnyFieldName8: 'AnyFieldValue8',
                AnyFieldName9: 'AnyFieldValue9',
                AnyFieldName10: 'AnyFieldValue10'
            },
            validationErrorCallback: function(){console.log('error in validating injected data');}
        })">Click to chat</button>
-->
```

### EDIT:

A chat bubble icon has been added.

Comment: That is really helpful, thank you. I now want to transform the start chat button to have a bubble chat icon

Comment: @VYSZ The code has been updated, done ☑️

Comment: If this answered your question, you should mark it as the correct answer.